# My column is seem NaN although I have elements in it

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

customers = {
    "CustomerId": [1,2,3,4],
    "FirstName" : ["Ahmet","Ali","Hasan","Canan"],
    "LastName" : ["Yılmaz","Korkmaz","Çelik","Toprak"]
}

orders = {
    "OrderId" : [10,11,12,13],
    "CustomerId" : [1,2,5,7],
    "OrderDate" : ["2010-07-04","2010-08-04","2010-07-07","2012-07-04"]
}

df_customers = pd.DataFrame(customers, columns = ["CustomerId","FirstName","LastName"])

df_orders = pd.DataFrame(orders, columns = ["orderId","CustomerId","OrderDate"])

print(df_orders)
```

Comment: İn the output There is full of NaN's under OrderId column

Comment: Change `orderId` to `OrderId` in `df_orders` line. Note the capital "O".

Comment: Also, you don't need to specify `columns` once you're using a dictionary as input.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva thanks a lot ! Yes you are right. Apparently I didn't mention that I've done such mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a `dict` you can simply use:

```
df_orders = pd.DataFrame(orders)

#   OrderId  CustomerId   OrderDate
#0       10           1  2010-07-04
#1       11           2  2010-08-04
#2       12           5  2010-07-07
#3       13           7  2012-07-04
```